# Highcharts: Flush chart against the sides

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is this "artifact" fixable?

[image]

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xL5wF/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'A',
        data: [10358, 10295, 10104 ]
    }, {
        name: 'B',
        data: [18000, 17000, 16000]
    }]
});
```

I've tried playing with `min` and `pointPlacement` to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `minPadding` and `maxPadding`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/xL5wF/1/